# How to get rows from two table in the same xpath expression?

Tags: c#, xpath, html-agility-pack

I'm using `HtmlAgilityPack`. Suppose I have the following situation:

```
<div class="main container">
   <div class="left">
       <table>
           <tbody>
             <tr />
             <tr />
             <tr />
           </tbody>
      </table>
   </div>
   <div class="right">
       <table>
           <tbody>
             <tr />
             <tr />
             <tr />
           </tbody>
      </table>
   </div>
```

I want get all the rows contained in the `tbody` from the two table of `left` and `right`, contained in the `main container` div.

I tried:

```
HtmlNode main = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[@class='main container']");

HtmlNodeCollection rows = main.SelectNodes("//table//tr");
```

but this will return all the rows of the document, I need only the rows of the two table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
main.SelectNodes("/table//tr");
```

When starting the SelectNode with two slashes, it restarts the search from the root document instead of the current path. I believe that's your issue.